# How to Install ArcGIS 10.2

Tags: installation, arcgis-10.2

I found out that [ArcGIS 10.2 was released yesterday](http://www.esri.com/esri-news/releases/13-3qtr/arcgis-102-delivers-transformational-capabilities), which is great since I am looking forward to it. Although so far I haven't been able to find any information on how the update will be installed.

I was hoping that it would be more of a patch update, but alas nothing to be found [here](http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/patches-servicepacks/list/productid/160).

So it's probably a full uninstall and re-install similar to 10.0 to 10.1. Does anyone have any concrete information (with s source) on this?

Comment: This is what's on the download page about the update: "The ArcGIS 10.2 setup package is designed to detect and upgrade an existing installation of the same ArcGIS 10.1 product (including SP1). The settings for the installation location, license manager (for Concurrent Use), or authorization information (for Single Use) are retained in the upgrade. See the installation guide for more information on installation upgrades, new installations, or installations over versions previous to 10.1."

Comment: you can download it from here http://support.esri.com/en/ after you sign into your customer account.

Comment: I had to uninstall and reinstall Workstation and point it to the license server.  It otherwise found the license manager and authorization files.  It took quite a while to remove the old and install the new.  As an FYI, it didn't open using my current templates, and when I tried to use them they were a mess.  I've had to customize from scratch and the jumping toolbars are back.  So you might get your work done and save a block of time for the install.

Comment: Which ArcGIS product(s) are you looking to install?  Yesterday I installed ArcGIS for Desktop 10.2 Single Use straight over the top of 10.1 SP1 (as was advertised on Customer Portal) and it worked without a hitch and remembered my license details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instructions for installing ArcGIS 10.2 can be found on ESRI's [ArcGIS Resources site](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/install-guides/arcgis-desktop/10.2/).

Comment: Geez, they already have a 10.2 Resources site as well. Well I guess it is just the same as 10.2 but re-branded for 10.2

Comment: FWIW, I just did a 10.2 install/upgrade over a 10.0 install and it prompted me to uninstall 10.0 first. Then installation went on as usual. However, 10.2 doesn't like our current FlexLM version and is demanding an upgrade on that before I can get a ArcGIS license. D'OH!